# How to use C# reflection to get properties that are instantiated or properties of a class type that are not null

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core, system.reflection

I'm new to reflection, I want to know how to filter out the private properties and also get only the properties that are instantiated. Sample of what I would like to achieve is given below.

```cs
public class PersonalDetails
{
    internal Address AddressDetails { get; set; }
    public Contact ContactDetals { get; set; }
    public List<PersonalDetails> Friends { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    private int TempValue { get; set; }
    private int Id { get; set; }

    public PersonalDetails()
    {
        Id = 1;
        TempValue = 5;
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string MailingAddress { get; set; }
    public string ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
    public string OfficePhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

PersonalDetails pd = new PersonalDetails();
pd.FirstName = "First Name";
pd.ContactDetals = new Contact();
pd.ContactDetals.CellNumber = "666 666 666";
```

When I get the properties of object *pd* I want to filter out the properties that are private and not instantiated, like properties *TempValue*, *Id* and *AddressDetails*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TempValue` is always instantiated, its a *value type*, do you mean all where not set to `default` (for an `int` that is `0`). also where is your reflection code?

Comment: yes, the private properties may be instantiated, but since they are private I want to avoid them.

Comment: I basically want properties that are not private and instantiated including the value types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

```
var p = new PersonalDetails();

var properties = p.GetType()
                  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                  .Where(x => x.GetValue(p) != null && !x.GetMethod.IsPrivate && !x.SetMethod.IsPrivate)
                  .ToList();
```

---

Additional Resources

[BindingFlags Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8)

> Specifies flags that control binding and the way in which the search
>   for members and types is conducted by reflection.

[PropertyInfo.GetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the property value of a specified object.

Comment: Will this also pull the property with an internal modifier, as the BindingFlag is public?

Comment: @BipinR so you want internal as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm basically doing var properties = pd.GetType().GetProperties(); but it is only pulling the public properties, but not internal, if I use BindingFlag.NonPublic it is bringing the private properties too.

Comment: @BipinR small mod, i forgot to add `SetMethod`